# A list of objects with dynamic type elements

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects in which one element `operand` could be of dynamic type a string, number or a map.
I defined the variable as follow:

```
variable "settings" {
  type = list(object({
    type=string
    operator=string
    operand=any
    ...
  }))
}
```

And from calling module, assigning values like below:

```
 settings = [    
    { "operator" = "lessThan", "type" = "responseTime", "operand" = 10000 },
    { "operator" = "is", "type" = "statusCode", "operand" = 200 },
    { "operator" = "is", "property" = "content-type", "type" = "header", "operand" = "abc" },
    { "operator" = "validatesJSONPath", "type" = "body", "operand" = { "operator" = "contains", "operandValue" = "google", "jsonPath" = "id" } }
  ]
```

However, this is throwing me following error:

```
The given value is not suitable for child module variable "settings" defined at operator\variables.tf:64,1-21: cannot find a common base type for all elements.
```

How best can I address this?

Comment: Amusingly, this config would cause a segfault in version 0.12. Anyway, `any` is a bit misleading of a name for the type, and I have made the same mistake before. `any` does not mean it can be "any" different type, but rather that the type can be "any" one unknown type when you declare it. I believe what you are exactly trying to do is not possible because of Golang `map` merging, deserialization, marshalling, or some behavior along those lines.You may have to specify the `type` as merely `list`.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about Terraform type constraints, you should understand `any` as asking Terraform to automatically infer a concrete type to replace it. `any` isn't a type in itself, but is instead a placeholder for one.

In your case, you've effectively asked Terraform to infer an element type for the list which matches the constraint. This plays out a little differently than the simpler case of `list(any)`, but still has the same constraint: Terraform needs to find one single concrete type to replace `any` with, and then convert all of the list elements to be of that type.

---

The situation you're describing seems like you'd prefer Terraform to behave like a dynamically-typed language rather than a statically-typed one, where it just takes whatever value you give it and then check dynamically whether it's shaped in a suitable way, as in [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

You can achieve that in Terraform by setting `type = any`, which asks Terraform to automatically infer a type for the *entire value*, which effectively applies no constraint at all because the value already has a concrete type and so `any` will be replaced with that type directly.

If you wish you can then just use the value elsewhere in your module, like `var.settings[0].operand.operator`, and Terraform will succeed in evaluating that if the structure matches and raise a dynamic operation error if not, just as we typically see in dynamic programming languages like Python.

You can also find a middle-ground by imposing some validation checks on the variable itself, which is roughly equivalent to starting a Python function with some explicit validation of each of the arguments and returning an error if they don't "quack like a duck":

```
variable "settings" {
  type = any

  validation {
    condition     = alltrue([for o in var.settings : can(tostring(o.operator))])
    error_message = "Each element must be an object with a string attribute named \"operator\"."
  }

  # ... and any other similar validation rules you want
}
```

A nice benefit of using explicit `validation` blocks like this, rather than just letting expressions fail inline inside the module, is that Terraform will attribute these validation failures to the argument inside the calling `module` block, rather than to some implementation detail inside the module. It will therefore appear to the caller as a problem with their module *call*, rather than a bug in the module itself.

Comment: This should probably be added as a note to the documentation given how frequently this use case arises, and with no explicit solution currently existing in the documentation. Similarly motivated documentation snippet to explain rationale: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Comment: @Martin Even if i make the `settings` variable of type `any` i get `Inappropriate value for attribute "operand": string required.`. Assuming thats because from above 3 instance it infered the type to be string but then in last when it found a map it threw this error.

Comment: If `type = any` then there wouldn't be a reason for Terraform to think that `operand` must be a string unless there's something else constraining it. I don't see anything I suggested here that would create that constraint, but maybe there's something elsewhere in your module.